# Trouble with PHP form and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I’m trying to submit a form with data to a php file without reloading the page. I also have some js code that changes the form name and values when the next btn is clicked. I had 10 questions all on 1 page and I got it to work with PHP but now I’m trying to get 1 question per page. I looked in the network tab and it looks like the xhr requests are being sent but in my database.php file I wrote $user_anwser = $_POST[‘quiz_1’]; and var dumped it and I get a NULL value. Here is the ajax code.

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){

    if (ind < 10){
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        form.setAttribute("action", "results.php");
    }

    let data = new FormData(form);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '../private/database.php');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            // if the response is json encoded
            let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); // i get a parse error there

            if (response.message == 'valid') {
                // redirect here
            }
        }
    // }
    xhr.send(data); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Does `data` contain what you expect it to?  Does the subsequent HTTP request in your browser's debugging tools contain what you expect it to?  What does `database.php` do with that form data?  When you debug, where specifically does the problem first manifest?

Comment: First, add a `console.log(xhr.responseText)` to the onload function. Second, show us your php code

Comment: If the network request has the data sending the issue must be on the PHP side. Please add PHP code.

Comment: Tell me about this part: `if (ind < 10){
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        form.setAttribute("action", "results.php");
    }`...what's the intention here? If ind is less than 10 it will prevent default postback, and then the ajax call fires, all fine. But if ind is 10 or more, you change the form's action attribute (so it will submit to a different endpoint) and you don't stop it from doing a normal postback, yet at the same time the ajax request will continue anyway. It doesn't quite make sense...do you really want to post back _and_ do an AJAX call?

Comment: ind is the question number. When it gets to the last question which is 10 it will go to the results.php page. For some reason console.log doesn’t work with MAMP so I gotta alert it. Yeah nothing happens when I put alert(xhr.responseText); in that function.

Comment: "When it gets to the last question which is 10 it will go to the results.php page"...yes but surely then in that case you don't want to send the ajax as well?

Comment: Here is the whole project under branch version2 the master is the first version on the project where all 10 questions were on 1 page and all the values were submitted together. Now I’m trying to use ajax to submit values 1 by 1 on 1 page. https://github.com/tianniNakiMyers/Quiz_App/tree/version2

Comment: that doesn't answer my question...and also if you have any relevant code please post it here, don't make us wade through your whole application code to find it

Comment: I think, you have wrong path to php file.
Try to change `xhr.open('POST', '../private/database.php');` to that `xhr.open('POST', '/private/database.php');`. This new path will point to your `root/private/database.php`. If this won't work, tell me plz what folder structure do you have on server side. And one more thing! Why do you use `onload` event ? All docs sad that you need to use `onreadystatechange` and in function check `this.readyState != 4` then return and `this.status != 200` then error! If non of that triggered than you are free to do "magic" in your js.

Comment: I already did... the database.php file has the code $user_answer = $_POST[quiz_1];

Comment: Well, have you changed path in xhr ? This was your error ? 

In database php use `var_dump($_POST);` and tell what you have ?

Comment: I tried changing the path, it didn’t work. I didn’t get any errors. I var_dumped $_POST and it’s an empty array. and @Petya my project is on github github.com/tianniNakiMyers/Quiz_App/tree/version2

Comment: I got it :) Your private dir doesn't available from the web! Right? You root dir is `public` and you hide your `private`. Move your `database.php` to public for testing and don't forget to change path in your JS. I think you will have all work as you planed! If so, you need to make a handler in `public` that will call all needed stuff from 'private'.

Comment: Instead of moving the database.php file I just changed the path for the ajax request to results.php since index.php, quiz.php and results.php are in the same public directory. Now when I go through the quiz I var_dump on results.php but I only get the last value lol but at least you got my biggest prob solved thanks a lot Petya!

Comment: You are welcome!
Check `let data = new FormData(form);` May be `data` doesn't containing all needed fields